# Invalid parameter number when updating multiple rows using case when in PDO

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdo, case

I need help on updating multiple rows at once in PDO. I'm using `UPDATE SET CASE WHEN` for that purpose, but I got really confused in binding the values to positional placeholders. Suppose my `$_POST` content is this:

$_POST["tid"]:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 383
    [1] => 386
)
```

$_POST["age"]:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 45
    [1] => 30
)
```

Then the $sql should be:

```
 UPDATE `person` SET age = CASE  
 WHEN user_id = ? AND tid = ? THEN ? 
 WHEN user_id = ? AND tid = ? THEN ? 
 ELSE `age` END
```

The code below is giving me this error

```
 [HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens
```

I'm looking to generate the correct number of bound variables like this:

```
$users->bindValue(1, $_SESSION["user_id"]); 
$users->bindValue(2, 383);
$users->bindValue(3, 45);
$users->bindValue(4, $_SESSION["user_id"]); 
$users->bindValue(5, 386);
$users->bindValue(6, 30);
```

Is there anything wrong with the code below?

```
 try
 {
   $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$databasename", $username, $password);
   $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
   $tid = $_POST["tid"];
   $age = $_POST["age"];
   $count = count($tid);

   for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++)
   {
      $wa .= " WHEN user_id = ? AND tid = ? THEN ?";            
   }

   $sql = "UPDATE `person` SET `age` = CASE $wa ELSE `age` END";

   $users = $dbh->prepare($sql);

   for($i=1;$i<$count;$i+=3)
   {    
      $users->bindValue($i, $_SESSION["user_id"]); 
   }

   $j = 2;
   foreach($tid as $t)
   { 
      $users->bindValue($j, $t);
      $j+=3;
   }
   $k = 3;
   foreach($age as $a)
   {
      $users->bindValue($k, $a);
      $k+=3;
   }

   $users->execute();        
   $dbh = null;

}
catch(PDOException $e) 
{
   echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: does the code without "foreach" way work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first loop is wrong. The end test doesn't account for the fact that you're incrementing by 3.

```
   for($i=1;$i<$count*3;$i+=3)
   {    
      $users->bindValue($i, $_SESSION["user_id"]); 
   }
```

Or you can do everything in one loop:

```
   for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++)
   {    
      $users->bindValue(3*$i+1, $_SESSION["user_id"]); 
      $users->bindValue(3*$i+2, $tid[$i]);
      $users->bindValue(3*$i+3, $age[$i]);
   }
```